# Queuing in review queue

Tags: support, review

Yesterday I saw the following [standard question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445507/does-there-exist-a-function-satisfying-the-given-conditionstifr-mathematics-gs), thus I search using google and find 3 other similar questions in MSE. I choose the (IMO) best one and voted to close the other 3 as duplicates. My votes were cast within 5 mins time.

However, I notice that they have different fate in the close vote review: [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445507/does-there-exist-a-function-satisfying-the-given-conditionstifr-mathematics-gs) showed up in the review queue and was then [closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/875782). The other two [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428487/h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851983/if-f-is-holder-continuous-for-alpha-1-then-f-is-constant), if I was corrected, was not found in the close vote queue yet.

I thought my close votes will automatically send the question to the review queue, but I might be wrong. Will the questions go to the review queue at all?

Comment: The Close Review Queue is the biggest, currently having about $180$ posts.  I don't know a way to check if a particular Question is in it.  Michael Hardy recently mentioned [using tags to search the Review Queues](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26997/the-filter-in-the-review-queue-ought-to-filter), so it might possible.

Comment: Heh, I tried filtering on [tag:real-analysis] and close reason "duplicate", and it pulled up your proposed close-as-duplicate [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428487/h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function).  So, it's there, just buried in the pile of items to review.

Comment: The question [If $f$ is holder continuous for $\alpha >1$ then $f$ is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1851983) (the one you marked 2) is still in the [review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/875783). So is the question [Hölder- continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428487) (1 in your notation) - https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/875784.

Comment: @hardmath I'll just add that the OP would probably not see the question using filtering via tags - AFAIK you are not offered to review questions you already voted on. If at least one user reviewed the question, it is possible to see it [in the review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) - which is what I did. (But it might be cumbersome solution - depending on the age maybe you need to go through several pages.) I will add that review is shown on the [timeline of the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) but only *after* it is finished.

Comment: I am not sure if this is done, but it could make sense that old questions get lower priority than new ones.

Comment: @quid, yes, that's probably the situation, the older one show up later.

Comment: Both the "other two" duplicates have now been closed as such.